# Converting XACML digital policies into CASPIN rulesets

Tags: access-control, xacml

Is there a tool or method to convert XACML ABAC digital policies into ruleset in CASPIN? Also, there are no complex examples of CASPIN supporting multiple rulesets like in a group policy. Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have a link to the definition of c a s p i n policies?

Comment: I think you meant to write casbin, right?

Comment: See: https://github.com/casbin/xacml-to-casbin-translator